# SchemaSpyGUI : Failed to query Graphviz version information

Tags: mysql, schemaspy

I need to get mySQL database schema output in html format, so I started working on this with SchemaSpyGUI.

Now, when I click on Start SchemaSpy it generate with this errors :

> Failed to query Graphviz version information
>     with: dot -V
>     java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dot": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Using database properties:
>     [D:\Saurin\mySQL\schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar]/net/sourceforge/schemaspy/dbTypes/mysql.properties

--

> Failed to connect to database URL [jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.11/dbmsTest]

Note: I downloaded graphviz from : http://www.graphviz.org/Download.php

and set dot in environment variable too;

Comment: Have you tried using SchemaSpy without SchemaSpyGUI?

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu Linux 14.04 I solved this just installing `graphviz`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install graphviz
[...]
$ dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.36.0 (20140111.2315)
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep both schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar & mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar files in same folder and keep installed graphviz installed folder outside program files/program files(X 86).

EX:-D:\jars> java -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -t mysql -o output -host localhost -db cmltDB -u cmlt -p cmlt123 -hq -dp mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar -gv D:\Graphviz2.38

Comment: Moving mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar into the schemaspy folder did it for me (after wasting hours on many other attempts). Windows 7Pro 32bit....

Answer (score 0):

@guests's answer includes the solution and works for me.
You can specify the path to GraphViz manually in the parameters.

Like:

```
-gv "c:\program files\graphviz2.38"
```

if that's where GraphViz is installed on your computer.

As you are using the GUI directly, type that into *Properties Directly:*